# How can i listen to Prestashop events in custom.js?

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In the compiled theme.js i can find event listeners like `prestashop.on("updatedProduct")` and `prestashop.on("clickQuickView")`.
More about those [here](http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/javascript/index.html).

I cannot get the web pack to work, so i would like to just add a listener in the custom.js (i know this is bad practice, i just need a quick solution).

How do i refer to this `prestashop` in custom.js, so i can listen for an event like `updateProductList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bulletproof answer :

```
         $(document).ready(function () {

            if(typeof prestashop !== 'undefined') {
                prestashop.on(
                  'updateCart',
                  function (event) {
                    if(typeof event.reason.linkAction !== "undefined" && event.reason.linkAction == "add-to-cart") {
                        if (typeof event.reason.idProduct == "undefined" || event.reason.idProduct == "undefined") {
                            // Bulletproofed action
                        }
                    }
                  }
                );
            }

         });
```

Comment: But there is no prestashop element available like that, so i'm afraid that won't work :/ i don't know how to refer to this prestashop element.

Comment: Do you know how to use developper console ? Just try inside it and you will be fixed, but i'm pretty comfident it will work :)

Comment: Okay it seems to work nicely through the console, but it doesn't with the exact same code placed in custom.js. Am i missing something? :)

Comment: It works! I forgot i recently enabled CCC, so it needed a cache reset doh... Thank you so much!